# How would one justify the answer to this question on derivatives?

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives

I couldn't understand the solution to the following problem:

*Suppose a balloon of volume V and radius r is being inflated, so that V and r are both functions of the time t. If dV/dt is constant, what can be said (without calculation)
about the behavior of dr/dt as r increases?*

The answers page says that the answer is:

*dr/dt decreases as r increases.*

I don't really understand why that answer is true.

I thought that r should has an increasing rate just like the volume, since the volume is dependent on the radius.

If anyone is interested, the question is from the book *Calculus and Analytic Geometry* by George Simmons, page 68, section 2.4, problem no. 17
The answer is in page 859.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $dr/dt$ is positive, but a positive function can be decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have:
$$V=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$$
Therefore:
$$\frac{dV}{dr}=4\pi r^2$$
And:
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=k$$
Where $k$ is some constant.
Now, use the fact that:
$$\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dt}/ \frac{dV}{dr}$$
From this, you can clearly see that as $r$ increases, $\frac{dr}{dt}$ decreases.

This is obvious enough to deduce, even 'without calculation' (As $r^2$ is increasing, in consequence its reciprocal must be decreasing).

Comment: I know this answer is from a while ago, but how do you know to divide $\frac{dV}{dt}$ by $\frac{dV}{dr}$ to find $\frac{dr}{dt}$?

Thank you.

Comment: From the chain rule: $$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac {dV}{dr}\frac{dr}{dt}$$ Now with easy algebraic manipulation, we get the result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this counts as "without calculation", but:  $V = \frac{4\pi}{3} r^3$.  This means that $dV/dt = 4 \pi r^2 (dr/dt)$.  Since $dV/dt$ is constant, and $r^2$ is increasing, $dr/dt$ must be decreasing to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $V=\frac{4\pi}{3}r^3(t)$.  Hence,

$$\frac{dV(t)}{dt}=4\pi r^2(t)\frac{dr(t)}{dt} \tag 1$$

We are given that $\frac{dV(t)}{dt}$ is constant and positive.  Let's call this constant $C>0$.  Then, we can write

$$\frac{dr(t)}{dt}=\frac{C}{4\pi r^2(t)} \tag 2$$

Differentiating $(2)$ reveals

$$\frac{d^2r(t)}{dt^2}=-\frac{C}{2\pi r^3(t)} \frac{dr(t)}{dt}<0$$

And we are done!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark